# How to use Tensorboard in AWS Sagemaker

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, tensorflow2.0, tensorboard, amazon-sagemaker

**I am referring to the links below to use Tensorboard in Sagemaker Script Mode method.**

https://www.tensorflow.org/tensorboard/get_started

https://levelup.gitconnected.com/how-to-use-tensorboard-in-an-amazon-sagemaker-notebook-instance-a41ce2fd973f

https://towardsdatascience.com/using-tensorboard-in-an-amazon-sagemaker-pytorch-training-job-a-step-by-step-tutorial-19b2b9eb4d1c

**Below is my tensorboard callback in my training script which is a .py file**

```
model = create_model()
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
log_dir = "logs/fit/" + datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")
tensorboard_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir=log_dir, histogram_freq=1)
model.fit(x=x_train, 
          y=y_train, 
          epochs=5, 
          validation_data=(x_test, y_test), 
          callbacks=[tensorboard_callback])
```

**In a notebook, I am creating the below Tensorflow Estimator where I am passing the above Script file name as entry_point.**

```
estimator = TensorFlow(
    entry_point='Script_File.py',
    train_instance_type=train_instance_type,
    train_instance_count=1,
    model_dir=model_dir,
    hyperparameters=hyperparameters,
    role=sagemaker.get_execution_role(),
    base_job_name='tf-fashion-mnist',
    framework_version='1.12.0', 
    py_version='py3',
    output_path=<S3 Path>,
    script_mode=True,
)
```

**I am using the below code in my notebook to start the training.**

```
estimator.fit(inputs)
```

**Once training is done, I am using the below code in a Terminal(have tried in my Notebook cell as well) to launch tensorboard.**

```
tensorboard --logdir logs/fit
```

But in the tensorboard I am not able to view any graphs. It is showing the message "Failed to fetch runs".
Is there something that I am missing? Or do I have to do any extra setting in my script to see my logs in Tensorboard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your tensorboard `logdir` is not `logs/fit`.. but there is the current date appended. Try using a `logs/fit` as `log_dir` and see if it's working.

EDIT

If you want to use tensorboard locally you have to send tensorboard logs to S3 and read from there. In order to do this you have to do what your third linked example does, so include sagemaker debugger:

> from sagemaker.debugger import TensorBoardOutputConfig
>
> tensorboard_output_config = TensorBoardOutputConfig(
> s3_output_path='s3://path/for/tensorboard/data/emission',
> container_local_output_path='/local/path/for/tensorboard/data/emission'
> )

then your tensorboard command will be something like:

> AWS_REGION= <your-region> AWS_LOG_LEVEL=3 tensorboard --logdir
> s3://path/for/tensorboard/data/emission

Alternatively if you want to use tensorboard in the notebook you have to do what the second linked example does, so simply install in a cell and run tensorboard with something like:

https://<notebook instance hostname>/proxy/6006/

Comment: Thanks for your reply @rok.
I tried giving the "log_dir" but still facing the same issue.

Comment: please clarify where do you launch tensorboard? Where are your training code running? Is that a notebook ? Post code to start the training job please.

Comment: My training code is a .py script(Because I am using Script mode) and I am storing it in the same folder as my notebook. The training code in this script is as shown above.
Please refer the updated question for the code to start training job.

Comment: I edited my reply, take a look. Basically you have 2 options to use tensorboard locally (pointing to s3 bucket) or in the notebook.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
I have tried both the methods. Even though I can see some event files while using both the methods(in S3 bucket and in local path), nothing shows up in the Tensorboard. I get the error as "Failed to fetch runs".

Comment: could be a bug in tensorboard ? read here https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/45335   may you try to downgrade it a see if it works?

Comment: Thankyou @rok for the suggestion. I downgraded my Tensorflow to version-2.2.0 and now I am able to see the graphs in my Tensorboard.